# EnumProcessModules returns invalid handle on valid handle

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program, that will enumerate all the modules in CSGO. But Handle seems somehow invalid for the EnumProcessModules function. It is non zero, and working fine otherwise. Have tried to run it as an admin, but the result remains the same

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

struct ret
{
    HANDLE pHandle;
    DWORD pid, bytes;
    HMODULE hmod[1024];
};

ret GetHandleToCSGO()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE tHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (Process32First(tHandle, &pe))
    {
        while (Process32Next(tHandle, &pe))
        {
            if (!strcmp(pe.szExeFile,"csgo.exe"))
            {
                ret r;
                r.pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pe.th32ProcessID);
                r.pid = pe.th32ProcessID;

                CloseHandle(tHandle);
                return r;
            }
        }
    }
}

void enummodules(ret)
{
    ret r;
    if (EnumProcessModules(r.pHandle, r.hmod, sizeof(r.hmod), &r.bytes))
    {
        for (int64_t i = 0; i < (r.bytes / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
        {
            TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];

            if (GetModuleFileNameEx(r.pHandle, r.hmod[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
                printf(TEXT("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, r.hmod[i]);
        }
    }
    else
        cout << GetLastError();
}

int main()
{
    ret r; r = GetHandleToCSGO(); 
    cout << r.pHandle;  
    enummodules(r);
}
```

Comment: `r.pHandle` passed to `EnumProcessModules` is uninitialized. You have to initialize it first.

Comment: @MikeCAT It is initialised by ```GetHandleToCSGO()``` which return value is stored and then passed to the ```enummodules(ret)```

Comment: Also it looks weird that the value received from `GetHandleToCSGO()` and passed to `enummodules()` is ignored from `enummmodules()`.

Comment: But how it could be ignored if it is saved?

Comment: @MikeCAT How it looks like - https://prnt.sc/t7tbmh

Comment: By not using the values. Your code refuses to receive the values by not giving the argument a name. Some of possible fixes are : 1. remove `ret r;` and declare the argument as `r` 2. copy data from the argument to `r`

Comment: `GetHandleToCSGO` has pathes where no `ret` is returned. Are you sure you don't run into those?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Docs have tutorials on both these subjects which show you how it must be done

- [enumerating processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes)
- [enumerating modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process)

You should be error checking the return value from CreateToolHelp32Snapshot()

Because you're using a while loop instead of a do while loop, you're actually skipping the first process.  Not all paths have a return value, your IDE should warn you that there is a problem with that.

Your enummodules doesn't actually take input, you create a local scope ret instead of using the one you passed.

Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

struct ret
{
    HANDLE pHandle;
    DWORD pid, bytes;
    HMODULE hmod[1024];
};

ret GetHandleToCSGO()
{
    ret r{ 0 };

    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE tHandle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (Process32First(tHandle, &pe))
    {
        do
        {
            if (!_stricmp(pe.szExeFile, "csgo.exe"))
            {
                r.pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pe.th32ProcessID);
                r.pid = pe.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(tHandle, &pe));
    }

    CloseHandle(tHandle);
    return r;
}

void enummodules(ret r)
{
    if (EnumProcessModules(r.pHandle, r.hmod, sizeof(r.hmod), &r.bytes))
    {
        for (int64_t i = 0; i < (r.bytes / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
        {
            TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];

            if (GetModuleFileNameEx(r.pHandle, r.hmod[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
                printf(TEXT("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, (unsigned int)r.hmod[i]);
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "last error: " << GetLastError();
}

int main()
{
    ret r; r = GetHandleToCSGO();
    cout << r.pHandle;
    enummodules(r);

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```